# Change an image for a second

Tags: java, android

```
     ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

     image.setImageResource(drawable.image1);
     SystemClock.sleep(1000);
     image.setImageResource(drawable.image2);
```

I am trying to change the image for a second, my code above doesn't work but not sure why?
Should I be using a thread? or does anyone have any better ideas?

EDIT
To clarify on the problem:

The image being displayed as "drawable.image2"
I want "drawable.image1" to be shown for one second then change to "drawable.image2".

EDIT2:

This code is used in the onClick. When a user clicks the image it needs to change for one second

Comment: `doesn't work`... what is not working? how is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a `TimerTask` with a `Timer`. You can set it up like this:

```
protected void showDelayedImages() {

    mImageView.setImageResource(resId1);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule( new MyTimerTask(), 1000 );
}

private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                mImageView.setImageResource(resId2);
            }
        } ); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

should do it. Although there are better ways too.

Answer (score 0):

Use debug mode and set breakpoints on each call to `setImageResource`. Step through and see if each is getting called to see if your image is changing properly.

In real world cases, you probably want to change the image based on some user action, or for example change an icon while a thread is processing, then change it bad when complete. For this example check out `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

use `R.drawable.image1` instead of `drawable.image1`

Comment: if `drawable` is referenced directly as an import this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're performing the "switch" in an onCreate() method, the `sleep` will probably just make your Activity load slower since at this stage there isn't actually anything written to the page.

To have your image change you need to perform the switch on the UI thread and you need to perform it after the image has been inflated and added to the page.

Try adding this code in an "onClick" event.